Create cylindrical slices of objects using geometry nodes
Create cylindrical slices of objects using geometry nodes.
I know we can create plane slices on various axes but how do we slice an object cylindrically in geometry nodes?
Example:
Original Object:

Horizontal Sliced object:

I'm trying to get various sized cylindrical shaped slices like the ones below using geometry nodes.

See attached blend file.


Do you have some mathematical formula to define the radius to keep/to remove ? Or is it an other object (i.e. a Mesh Line) ?

@StefLAncien No, I don't have a formula to define the radius.  I was trying to vary it.  You mentioned a mesh line.  That sounds interesting for using it to create the cylindrical thickness and spacing.

(Using Blender 4.2.4)
Overview
The cutting object is generated by extrusion of flat annuli. These are made with a Fill Curve node from Curve Circle(s) whose radius and sampling are controlled with an external 3D Line curve.

Setup
It is assumed that the cutting object axis is defined by the cut object origin and the Z direction.
The controlling curve is created in Object Mode using the menu entry Add>Curve>Line. Its location and orientation are irrelevant. But it is convenient to put its origin along the cut object Z axis and to extrude new control points in X direction. The radius of cutting cylinders is controlled by the Length along this curve. So in Edit Mode, moving control points in X direction changes the position and the thickness of cuts. The cylinders refinement in azimuth direction is controlled by the Radius attribute of each control point. The number of control points defines the number of cuts. For odd counts, the core cylinder is removed.
GeometryNodes modifier
The provided GeometryNodes graph is adapted by adding a new Group Node labelled "Cutter". It is selected with a Switch node instead of the original "Slice Object" Group Node. The controlling curve is recovered through the successive Group Input nodes.
1. A generic Curve Circle of Radius 1 is duplicated using an Instance on Points node. All these Points are collocated at the origin of the cut object. Consequently, all the spawned circles are concentric. It is to notice that the Curve Circle is finely discretized because it is a poly spline, not a NURBS or Bézier spline.
2. The number of cuts is computed from the number of control points recovered through a Domain Size node set in Curve domain. There is one less cut and the control points Index is offset by one to not take into account the curve origin, i.e. the first control point of Index 0.
3. The spawned circles of unitary radius are scaled in XY direction by the Length sampled at every control point.
4. This scale is applied using a Realize Instances node. The output is a single curve made of disjointed circular splines.
5. The refinement of each spline is independently set with a Resample Curve node set in Count mode. The number of control points is computed by multiplying a constant (arbitrarily chosen as 32 in the demonstration) with the Radius attribute of each control point. This value is recovered through an other Sample Index node.
6. Flat annuli are generated between pairs of splines, starting from the outer most, with a Fill Curve node.
7. The center and the size of the cut object in Z direction are computed from its Bounding Box. Its height is slightly increased by 0.1% to ensure that the extruded cutter is enclosing the cut object.
8. Annuli are moved in Z direction just below the cut object using a Transform Geometry node.
9. The cutter object is generated by extrusion of the annuli Faces in normal direction, i.e. Z.
10. The remaining mesh is computed by a Mesh Boolean node with the Intersect operation.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.4+)


Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
You can use a flat cone trick to spawn concentric circles, then give them thickness and use each separately in a mesh boolean.

Imgur mirror

